# Click en un elemento de un listview en Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando realizar el `onItemClickListener` de una lista que es actualizada mediante una base de datos en android studio pero no logro hacerlo.

Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo algo así
http://cursoandroidstudio.blogspot.com.co/2014/08/base-de-datos-remotas.html
pero no me deja de ninguna manera obtener la posición. ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe esto?

Comment: Andrey veo que es similar a lo que habias preguntado, añade el codigo de como lo tratas de realizar y especifica donde tienes el problema o que error tienes.

Comment: Sí la respuesta que te he proporcionado te ha resultado útil, por favor, márcala como correcta.

Comment: Es un poco tarde para responder, pero para la gente que le ocurra algo similar,...
Suponiendo que tienes un adaptador que te rellena el listview en el onCreate de la actividad.
No te va a funcionar nunca el Listener porque en **la actividad principal donde unes tu adaptador con el listview siempre va a ser null**. Estas haciendo referencia a algo que aun no existe. Por lo tanto, el listener SIEMPRE tienes que colocarlo en el adaptador y no en la actividad.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente añade un `setOnItemClickListener` a tu `ListView` y en base a la posición del objeto recibida realiza la acción que quieras.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position) {

      ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
      //Añade el código que quieras para tu item        
   }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Click en un elemento de un listview en Android?**

Para realizar esto, se debe asinar a tu `ListView` el listener:  [**`setOnItemClickListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))

es importante asegurar que tu ListView pueda realizar una acción al recibir un clic con   `setClickable(true);`

Este es un ejemplo,

```
listView.setClickable(true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    //Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    // Realiza lo que deseas, al recibir clic en el elemento de tu listView determinado por su posicion.
    Log.i("Click", "click en el elemento " + position + " de mi ListView");

  }
});
```