# Obtener posición de un ListView en Android

Tags: java, android

Deseo obtener el campo seleccionado en un listview que esta sincronizado con una base de datos remota, gracias al que me pueda colaborar.

Comment: Hola Andrey el que este sincronizado con una base de datos remota no influye en lo que deseas, que es obtener el elemento seleccionado dentro de un ListView, usa el método onItemClick del listener setOnItemClickListener del ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza un onItemClicListener.

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Como ves, te devuelve la posicion del item pulsado y la vista que lo contiene. Con esos dos parametros puedes buscarlo en el adapter o recuperarlos de la vista.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Supongo que esta pregunta es por lo mismo
[Click en un elemento de un listview en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10140/onitemclicklistener-listview-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener la posición del propio OnItemClickListener que añades a tu Listview. Por ejemplo:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position) {

      ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
      //Añade el código que quieras para tu posición usando la variable position    
   }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Obtener posición de un ListView en Android**

Para obtener la posición se puede realizar mediante el  listener [**setOnItemClickListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) y mediante su método [**onItemClick()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)),  puedes determinar la posición de la vista dentro de tu `ListView`, mediante el tercer parámetro que es `position` (posición):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

Log.i("Click", "click en el elemento " + position + " de mi ListView");

  }
});
```