# ¿ Método onClick en ListView?

Tags: java, android, lista

Tengo el siguiente ListView en un xml :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >

</ListView>
```

Y esto en el .main :

`public void cargar () {`

```
        BaseHelper baseHelper = new BaseHelper (this,"DEMODB",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        if(db!=null){

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Notas ORDER BY Primero DESC LIMIT 5",null);
            int cantidad = c.getCount();
            int i=0;
            String[] arreglo = new String [cantidad];


            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                do{

                    String linea = c.getInt(0)+"                   "+ c.getInt(1)+" Clicks";

                    arreglo[i] = linea;

                    i++;
                }while(c.moveToNext());

            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arreglo);
            ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

Que sirve para guardar datos en dicha listView. La línea de `String linea = c.getInt(0)+"                   "+ c.getInt(1)+" Clicks";` es la que dice qué escribir.

¿ Cómo puedo poner el método onClick para que al tocar un item de la lista haga cierta actividad?

Comment: Hay una respuesta en http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10140/click-en-un-elemento-de-un-listview-en-android

Comment: No es lo mismo, yo no quiero la posicion, yo quiero que me diga lo que hay en esa posicion....

Comment: No quiero la posicion tal como pone en ese enlace lo que yo quiero solo es LA INFORMACION DE CADA ITEM.

Answer (score 1):

Debes asignar a tu ListView el listener **`setOnItemClickListener`**, Recuerda que tienes que tener la referencia de tu `listView` antes y después asignarle el `listener`:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arreglo);
            ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {        
           //llama el método cargar();
           cargar();
          }
        });
```

El método `cargar()` debe contener únicamente el proceso que deseas realizar:

```
public void cargar () {

        BaseHelper baseHelper = new BaseHelper (this,"DEMODB",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        if(db!=null){

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Notas ORDER BY Primero DESC LIMIT 5",null);
            int cantidad = c.getCount();
            int i=0;
            String[] arreglo = new String [cantidad];


            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                do{

                    String linea = c.getInt(0)+"                   "+ c.getInt(1)+" Clicks";

                    arreglo[i] = linea;

                    i++;
                }while(c.moveToNext());

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Era eso lo que buscaba. Pero y si te digo que lo pongo y no hace absolutamente nada? .______.

Comment: Yo creo que hay que ponerlo y ya está no?

Comment: Espera que creo que el problema es el Log.i , wait.

Comment: Elena sí que funciona pero como consigo que me lea lo que tengo guardado en una posicion? (mira actualizacion)

Comment: En el ejemplo de Elena seria así: arg0.getItemAtPosition(position) a esta linea le tienes que hacer un cast del tipo de objeto de tu item y con eso conseguiras el valor que guarda cada item de tu listview.

Comment: Bourne, he puesto eso así con +arg0.getItemAtPosition(position) y sí que funciona, lo que pasa que me muestra además la posicion [i] de mi lista y eso no quiero, solo quiero lo que hay dentro.